# Random number problems

Tags: java, random, numbers

I have a bit of a complicated question. I'm currently trying to write a REALLY simple version of path finding, and to do that I need a way to generate number within a range, and each number must be different from all the others, and bigger than the last number. How would I go about doing this? So output would look like:

1,5,6,9,15,18

Comment: What is the range of numbers you want to random? Will you always need six numbers?

Comment: Depends on the distribution you want. Should this be a random sample of the given range, or should each number be uniformly distributed in the range between the previous number and the upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

Create a random generator function:

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    // Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

(code courtesy from an [answer by Greg Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java/363692#363692)).

Call this wherever you want and check as like:

```
int a;

a=randInt(min,max);
```

and for the next time parse the previously generated value, like:

```
randInt(a,  max);
```

Comment: Making a new generator on every call is a bad idea. You'll generate a new seed on every call and use it once; the seeds are likely to have undesirable properties, and it won't be as statistically sound as using a single generator (not that the default Java RNG is any good, but still).

Answer (score 0):

Use [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to pick *n* numbers from your range. Since you're going through the range in order the resulting list is sorted.

Comment: It works, but it's way slower than it could be. To reservoir sample from the range of all ints, you'd have to iterate through all ints. A better algorithm would take time proportional to the size of the required sample.

Comment: Well, the question looked like small ranges. Ideally you'd pick either reservoir sampling or rejection sampling depending on how large *n* and *k* are for picking *n* numbers from (0, *k*).